# Using BeautifulSoup for extracting text from webpage

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am new to Python programming I just installed Python (Version 3.5.2) and I am using Geany editor to write and execute my scripts.

I just tried this simple script but it is failing:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
r = urllib.urlopen('http://www.aflcio.org/Legislation-and-Politics/Legislative-Alerts').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(r)
```

Error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "soup.py", line 1, in <module>
>     from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
> ImportError: No module named 'bs4'
> ```

I have installed BeautifulSoup using `pip install bs4` and I get the successful output "Successfully installed bs4-0.0.1"

I understand this is a simple issue but any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you do-  `pip install beautifulsoup4` ?

Comment: The error says, and I quote: "Import Error: No module named 'bs4'". It means that there is no module named `bs4`. Try: `pip install beautifulsoup4` and look at the output where it ends up. Try `which python` and `which pip` to inspect the pip and python you use.

Comment: I tried both bs4 and beautifulsoup4.

Comment: allcaps: Here is the output after running pip install beautifulsoup4     "Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): beautifulsoup4 in c:\users\..\anaconda3\lib\site-packages"
You are using pip version 8.1.2, however version 9.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type "pip freeze" into the command line/terminal.  If you don't see bs4-0.0.1 in that list, it isn't installed.

If you do see it, you could try "pip uninstall bs4" then reinstall "pip install bs4".

Also, remember that "pip install" is a command line/terminal command.  You don't type it into the Python interpreter: you type it into the command line

Comment: Just ran "pip freeze" and I can see bs4==0.0.1

Comment: Try uninstalling it and reinstalling it, then.  Then try "import bs4" in the Python shell and see if it works.

Comment: Just did the same. And it goes back to the same error - "No module named bs4". I fail to understand whether I missed any basic configuration or anything if that's the reason?

Comment: I'm stumped too, this is odd.  I see you're on Windows from another comment.  Try going to your python installation folder and in "\Python\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages" and see if there's a folder called bs4 there.  Are you able to import other packages?  Just to test, try doing "pip install requests" and "import requests"

Comment: Yeah! I checked this earlier under site-packages and I did find the bs4 folder.

Comment: EDIT: Gosh! I just found 2 Python folders in 2 different directories. Guess that is causing the trouble. The one under C drive does not have bs4 installed. Bummer!

Comment: In that case, uninstall Python and then reinstall it.  Hopefully it'll clean up your installation!

Comment: Thanks jarcobi889. I tried cleaning up older versions and now it is working. Sigh!

Comment: Happy to hear it!  Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

The error means your interpreter can't find bs4. If you ran pip install bs4, try the following:

```
pip3 install bs4
```

pip3 is the Python3 specific pip. This answer doesn't apply on all platforms but you didn't provide yours :)

Comment: Thanks! I am using Windows OS. I tried pip3 and it failed.